# Explain the calendar in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The Elder Scrolls has always had an unusual calendar. Can someone translate the days of the week and month names? Actually, a thorough explanation of the calendar would be useful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Tamrielic calender is simply a Gregorian calender with different names, and without leap years.

From the [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Calendar):

[image]

[image]

Midyear, Hearthfire, and Frostfall are not consistent even within the games, alternating between references as a single compound word (i.e., Frostfall), and a pair of words (i.e., Frost Fall).

Furthermore, Hearthfire is referred to as Heartfire in Skyrim, despite some lore books continuing to list it as Hearthfire. (The last time it was referred to as Heartfire was in TES:Arena, so it's *possible* this is a regional dialect)

Answer (score 11):

According to the [UESPWiki.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Calendar)

Days

- Sundas = Sunday
- Morndas = Monday
- Tirdas = Tuesday
- Middas = Wednesday
- Turdas = Thursday
- Fredas = Friday
- Loredas = Saturday

Months

- Morning Star = January
- Sun's Dawn = February
- First Seed = March
- Rain's Hand = April
- Second Seed = May
- Mid Year = June
- Sun's Height = July
- Last Seed = August
- Hearthfire = September
- Frostfall = October
- Sun's Dusk = November
- Evening Star = December