# What year did Skyrim begin?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am currently in the year 4E 202 the 26th of some month?  What was the beginning year, and how much "game time" has passed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Skyrim starts at 4E 201, 200 years after the Third Era ended along with the Septim bloodline.

If you're playing on PC, you can type `help gamedayspassed` in the console to see how much time has passed in-game.

Comment: Yeah, @desaivv, the death(?) of Martin marked the end of the Third Era.

Comment: @desaivv The games do not determine the era, no. Consider that Oblivion was the fourth Elder Scrolls game, yet it was set in the *third* era! Rather, the game world has its own history, with numerous events well outside the scope of any game (e.g. the 200 years that have passed since Oblivion), and even events during the games happening elsewhere in the world. http://uesp.net/wiki/Lore:History

Answer (score 22):

The game of Skyrim starts on Sundas, the 17th of Last Seed, 4E201, at approximately 9:30.

[image]

If you don't know what Morndas or Last Seed are, I suggest you look at [the answer to this question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/43633/336)

Comment: It's only Morndas because [it was Morndas on your other save](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unbound#Notes).  For a brand-new game, it will be Sundas.

Answer (score -4):

Skyrim starts at 7.10 am, on the 17th of Last Seed (the 8th month out of 12) on a Sundas (equivalent to Sunday).

Comment: This directly contradicts the other answers on both the time and the day of the week. Considering the other answers are supported by references, this answer appears to be wrong.